# how do i store the results of my calcultions int an array

Tags: java, arrays

how do i store the result of  "week_result" i calculate into an array

```
 public double calculation() { 
`week_result =  round(((inWatts/100)*use_hours*3600/1000)*0.54,2);
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
        "weekly : " + week_result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
return week_result;
}

public static double round(double value, int places) {
if (places < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(value);
bd = bd.setScale(places, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
return bd.doubleValue();
}

}
```

and how can i add up all the values stored in this array in another class ....

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do:

```
ArrayList<Double> arr = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

To add elements to array in your case

```
double week_result = round(((inWatts/100)*use_hours*3600/1000)*0.54,2);
arr.add(week_result);
```

And to access this array from other classes, declare a getter method to return this ArrayList

```
public ArrayList<Double> getArray() {
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: works fine but how do i add up all the values it stores to a double variable and secondly how do i empty this arraylist ??

Comment: Please just read this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html .

There is a function called `clear()`

Comment: You can call `add` method anytime you want to add an element, and yea you need to read the link from Gregg also check the above link, it contains a good examples.

Answer (score 0):

Use an ArrayList as it will increase in size as and when more space is needed

```
ArrayList<Double> results = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

Add a result to the list using

```
results.add(result);
```

When you want to find the sum of the ArrayList use a foreach loop

```
sumList(ArrayList<Double> results) {
   double total = 0.0;
   for(double result : results) {
         total += result;
   }
   return total;
}
```

And call `sumList(results);`

Comment: sumList doesnt take ArrayList<Duoble> results

Answer (score -1):

As your function `calculation()` returns a value of type `double`, you can simply store this value in an array, or any variable, of type `double`, for example:

```
public double[] values = new double[10];
values[0] = calculation();
```